# How to understand the cast exception in automating Word from a VB code in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, automation, visual-studio-2019

I am developing a form application in the German Visual Studio 2019 that should automate Word using VB. In my VB project, I added a reference to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll and can compile the application. To debug the application in VS, I use the code:

```
    Dim oWord As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True
```

This trivial code should instantiate and show Word. However, I get the exception instead that Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass cannot be cast in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application

```
System.InvalidCastException: Das COM-Objekt des Typs "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass" kann nicht in den Schnittstellentyp "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application" umgewandelt werden. Dieser Vorgang konnte nicht durchgeführt werden, da der QueryInterface-Aufruf an die COM-Komponente für die Schnittstelle mit der IID "{00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" aufgrund des folgenden Fehlers nicht durchgeführt werden konnte: Fehler beim Laden der Typbibliothek/DLL. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))
```

As far as I understood, the reason is not quite clear. Some assume that the reason is installation of several Word versions that results in versions' incompatibility and the exception. To fix the problem, they suggest to delete double {00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} items in the Windows register. I tried it, but the problem remains.

How do I fix the problem or does somebody has a similar sample automation project in VB (VB# or VC++) I can experiment with?

Comment: No, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Your comment to Mary's answer implies that you have another project that works, but this problem is specific to this project. Try the following. 1) Backup your project. 2) Delete the Bin and Obj folders via Explorer.  3)In VS, delete all Office references and then add the Word reference again for the References->COM tab selecting "Microsoft Word XX.Y Object Library" (XX.Y will depend on the installed version). 4) Rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the file...

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

Then create the object with the New keyword which calls the constructor.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim oWord As New Word.Application
    oWord.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mary, but it doesn't work either and throws the same exception. I've already got a working VB-Project to test my environment and this project **doesn't work in my environment**.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this exception was Windows with a corrupt registry.